# Visio defaults settings changable?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I would like to change how much I can move a drawing object using shift key and arrow keys. I would like to make the increments very tight for precision moving of items like in AI to get lines to align perfectly. Is that possible, to change the default distances?

Comment: i am not sure if i understand, but when you press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while moving a object you have bigger precision. Under the Design tab / Layout group you can change the default distances. Look here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/q8mm9.png  .Does this solve your problem ?

Comment: please +1 and accept the question bellow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Visio when you press and hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while moving a object you have bigger precision. Under the Design Tab/Layout group options you can change the default distances. Look here:

[image: Visio Page Setup]